# How can i use autocomplete in IDE in this case in python

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, python-decorators

```
class Event(object):
    can_i_autocomplete_this = True

class App(object):
    def decorator(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def call():
        self.func(Event())

app = App()

@app.decorator
def hello(something):
   print(something.can_i_autocomplete_this)

app.call()
```

I use decorator like this.
but in this case, `something` parameter in hello method autocomplete doesn't work in IDE(pycharm). (must support python 2.7)

how can i use autocomplete in this case?

thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get PyCharm to auto-complete code in methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309279/how-to-get-pycharm-to-auto-complete-code-in-methods)

Answer (score 2):

Usages of function are not analyzed in inferring types of  parameters.

You could specify type of parameter inside doc:

```
@app.decorator
def hello(something):
    """
    :param something:
    :type something: Event
    :return:
    """
    print(something.can_i_autocomplete_this)
```

or using type hinting syntax (since Python 3.5):

```
@app.decorator
def hello(something: Event):
    print(something.can_i_autocomplete_this)
```