# Pycharm can not auto complete selenium package

Tags: selenium, pycharm

I install selenium through Python pip and write a simple file called  crawlTest.py, it works well.Later, I install Pycharm and try to  auto complete method  from selenium, but it doesn't work.

I guess Pycharm didn't  know where I install selenium and an external library is needed.But I try by myself and search on google and StackOverflow, I didn't  get proper  solution.

I have read the flowing posts, but still not work. It is very useful and
 time-saving for those who use selenium and Pycharm if some one could give me .

here is post list I hava viewed:

[How to get PyCharm to auto-complete code in methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309279/how-to-get-pycharm-to-auto-complete-code-in-methods)
 [PyCharm doesn't auto-completes very simple cases such as: import pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517535/pycharm-autocomplete)

Comment: ensure your project interpreter is the same one as you've installed selenium into. Auto completion should just work

Comment: thanks,Paul Collingwood，according to you suggestion,I have run the scrip , and found it doesn't  work with python2.7. So I change   my Interpreter as python3.5 in Pycham, then it work and Pycham can auto compete selenium functions.

Answer (score 0):

I install selenium by python pip, and it works with python3.5，but not python 2.7. so I changed my project interpreter as python 3.5 in Py . Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

for use auto-complete  Pycharm feture go to "File\Setting\Project:" add new interpreter and select you instaleed python directory.
[image]