# Static structure for instantiated dataclass attributes from JSON for PyCharm autocomplete

Tags: python, json, autocomplete, pycharm

I have a response from a server in the form of a json response that looks like this:

```
{
"paths": {
    "/machines" : {
        "get": {
            "Props": {
                "id": {
                    "name": "id"
                    "availableForFiltering": true,
                    "availableForSorting": true
                },
                "organization.id": {
                    "name": "organization.id"
                    "availableForFiltering": true,
                    "availableForSorting": false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The goal is get autocomplete suggestions in the IDE, and access it like `paths.machines.get.Props.id.name`. My approach for this is to make use of a dataclass as follows

```
@dataclass
class DynamicData:
    data: Dict[str, Any]

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.data:
            value = self.data[item]
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                return DynamicData(data=value)
            return value
        return None
```

While this works, I am not sure how to convert it back to some form of static form so that PyCharm can read the dataclass and give me autocomplete suggestions on it. As it is dynamically instantiated during runtime, autocomplete wouldn't work. I can only access it before running the code.

For now, I am just trying to figure out what would be the best way to save this instance with it's values and structure into a file that PYCharm can statically analyse upon import and give me autocomplete suggestions.

Any input is welcome.
Any critique on the approach is welcome too.

Comment: "*[...] and access it like `paths.machines.get.Props.id.name`*": What about `organization.id`, which is not a valid identifier?

Comment: Good catch. Not sure about that, but let's assume only valid identifiers exist.

Comment: I think yole's answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15022961) and [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311571) say it all.